# C# Visual Studio No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012

```
if (kmatch == 1)
{
    con.Open();

    int a;
    a = Convert.ToInt16(txtBalance.Text);
    a = int.Parse(txtBalance.Text);

    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    String query = "update PlayerAccount set Balance='" + a + "'where Player_User=" + txtUser.Text + "";
    com.CommandText = query;
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("PointCard Credited to your Account");
    con.Close();
}
```

At first I thought that it needed to be converted to `int`.
but now I am out of ideas.

Database
Table:PlayerAccount

'Balance' is an int

Just started learning this. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First you should convert this to use a parametrized query as currently its got  an SQL Injection vulnerability

Comment: You need to fix your query - remove `'` single quotes after `Balance='" + a + "'` since `a` is an integer it cannot be inside single quotes (those are for strings only), next you need to add a space before `where` so your query will look like this: `update PlayerAccount set Balance=" + a + " where Player_User='" + txtUser.Text + "'";`, like in the answer by @Michael below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31274651/448816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `String query = "update PlayerAccount set Balance='" + a + "'where Player_User=" + txtUser.Text + "";` to `String query = "update PlayerAccount set Balance= " + a + " where Player_User='" + txtUser.Text + "'";`.

You need to include single quotes around text values in SQL and you don't need to include them around numeric values (though you can if you wish).

However, it looks like you are opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

Look into using parameterized commands instead of dynamically writing SQL.

Documentation for SQL Parameters [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply , i wasn't aware of that but its all good now. Just one more question though. How do i make int a accumulate . like for example every time i put a number in a  i want Balance'+= Balance.

Comment: Your `SET` statement should be `... SET Balance = Balance + " + a + "...`

Answer (score 0):

```
"'where Player_User="
```

Should be

```
" 'where Player_User="
```

You are missing a space and appending too much together. But as Alex K. said you should convert this to a parametrized query.

Comment: This actually won't fix the issue. The space is not required as single quotes have been used to identify the value. The issue is the text (presumably) field `Player_User` being set to a non-text value since the single quotes are missing for that portion of the `where` statement.